# How to put an element in a different place (responsive)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make a responsive search bar which will be placed in a different place on desktop and mobile.
I build two differents search bar with different IDs, with `display: none` and `display: block`  and with the same jQuery code.

I have one problem:
- search input doesn't close anymore if I click on a other part than the search icon. With one search bar, input automatically close when I click anywhere.

With one search bar: [codepen.io/anon/pen/Adgpf](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Adgpf)

With two search bars: [codepen.io/anon/pen/ceHmn](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ceHmn)

Comment: Hard to tell without the accompanying html and css. This seems like a good candidate for Jsfiddle. (jsfiddle.net) Try throwing all the working code up there.

Comment: You shouldn't be creating two versions of what is essentially the same search element. Proper responsive elements should be manipulating the same element using css media queries or javascript to suite browser widths etc.

Comment: I tried with $("#search").remove().insertAfter... but it doesn't work. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Setup a demo on jsfiddle or somewhere if you want someone to check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're triggering this event twice, which inverts `isOpen`.. and then inverts it with the second click:

```
submitIcon.click();
```

so just trigger one of them and you avoid the double inversion:

```
submitIcon.eq(0).click();
```

and it works

**Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/baekD**

This is the simplest solution. Your code could use some refactoring.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Do you know why input text in the second sidebar is automatically deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).click(function(){
  if(!$('#sb-search').click()) {
    searchBox.removeClass('sb-search-open');
    isOpen = false;
  }
});
```

You may need to tweak it for your overall purpose but it solves your issue as seen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iBupA).

Answer (score 0):

I had create jsfiddle for the same, check it, may it will help you..

```
Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/patelbharat001/w0jzzbuy/
```